# How do I choose an SSL VPN plugin?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, networking, vpn

I want to set up a VPN on my phone so that I can access internal websites while I'm out of the office. We're doing VPN-over-https. I've found [the instructions on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn673608.aspx) but am baffled by this line:

> To utilize SSL-VPN, select the link shown and download a third-party plugin.

When I tap the link, I'm just dumped into the store. I mean it literally shows me Candy Crush. The VPN on my network is just the common-or-garden whatever you get with Windows. We haven't bought some sort of "VPN Solution" from a vendor. We can all connect to this VPN with laptops, tablets etc, but now I just want the phone to be able to come to the party.

Since the link didn't give me any Store search terms, what should I search for? And if I get a lot of hits (as I did when I tried SSL VPN) how do I distinguish between them?

Answer (score 1):

The same Microsoft article you linked to lists a number of third-party SSL VPN plug-ins for Windows Phone. The list is near the beginning, in the "VPN tunneling protocols" section:

> On Windows Phone 8.1, SSL-VPN methods are only supported via “proprietary” vendor plug-ins. These plug-ins need to be installed on the phone in order to connect to third-party VPN servers using SSL-VPN. Windows Phone 8.1 currently supports the following plug-ins, all of which can be downloaded via the Windows Phone store.
>
> - Juniper Networks JunOS Pulse VPN
> - SonicWall MobileConnect VPN
> - F5 Networks VPN
> - Checkpoint Mobile VPN

When I search the Store on my Lumia 920 for "ssl vpn", three of the four apps listed above - Junos Pulse VPN, Check Point Mobile VPN and SonicWALL Mobile Connect - are at the top of the results list.

However, as I understand, those apps all require a VPN solution by the respective vendor. If you don't use a third-party solution, then you shouldn't require a third-party VPN app either. It would seem that the link in VPN settings is somewhat ill-placed, implying a VPN app is required regardless of which type of VPN you're using, which is not the case.

Comment: You can't choose anything other than IKEv2 so until I install **something** SSL-VPN isn't going to be available. This list of 4 apps doesn't help me. Will any of them work with the built in Windows VPN-over-https, or are they just for their own VPN solutions? If they all work, what's the difference among them? Why on earth doesn't Microsoft have a plugin I can use? Etc etc etc.

Comment: As I said, the third-party apps are to be used with a VPN solution from the respective vendor. Since you don't use one of those, you should go with the default option - IKEv2. Have you actually tried it? The TechNet article you linked to includes a comprehensive guide.

Comment: About all i know about vpn is how to spell it :-). But I do know we want VPN over SSL. I don't even know what IKE is, v1 v2 or otherwise, but I have no reason to believe it would work with a server that's expecting SSL.